Sequelizer belongsToMany relations
I am trying to establish a belongsToMany relationship between two models, User and Company.
I think I have done everything right, but the funny thing is that the api shows me the results relationships when I query User, but when I try to query Company, it gives me the following error:
User is not associated to Company!
These are my two models and the relations:
user.model.js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', 
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      name:  { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      password:  { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true }   
    }, 
    {
      tableName: 'users',
      paranoid: true,
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true
    });

  User.associate = models => {
    User.belongsToMany(models.Company, { 
      through: 'CompanyUsers',
      as: 'companies',
      foreignKey: 'user_id'
    });
  };

  return User;
};

company.model.js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', 
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      code: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      disabled: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
    }, 
    {
      tableName: 'companies',
      paranoid: true,
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true      
    });

    Company.associate = models => {
      Company.belongsToMany(models.User, { 
        through: 'CompanyUsers',
        as: 'users',
        foreignKey: 'company_id'         
      });
    };

  return Company;
};

Any idea?
Thanks!!

UPDATED
Here de querys to obtain all users & all companies
company.service.js
import db from '../models/index.js';

const { Company, User } = db.db;

const findAll = async () => Company.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: User, as: 'users' },
  ],
});

user.service.js
import db from '../models/index.js';

const { User, Company } = db.db;

const findAll = async () => User.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: Company, as: 'companies' },
    ],
});

index.js
import fs from 'fs';
import { join, dirname, basename } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url';
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

import sequelize from '../config/sequelize.js';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const fileURL = new pathToFileURL(__dirname);
const base = basename(__filename);

const db = {};

const files = fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== base) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'));

await Promise.all(files.map(async file => {
  const model = (await import(join(fileURL.href, file))).default(sequelize, DataTypes);
  db[model.name] = model;
}));

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

//await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default {
  db,
};


Please add the Sequelize query you use to get companies to the post

I have already added the queries

Did you check associations prop in Company right before Company.findAll?

Yes, they are correct, as you can see in the models. I've added index.js

And do the associations have an association with Users using alias users there?
